# Mongoose eager loading?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mongoose

I have a problem concerning the return of a mongodb document.
I am using following call in my node.js server configuration:

```
app.get('/ruimtes/:afkortingCampus', function (req, res) {
  Ruimtes.find({'campusAfkorting': req.params.afkortingCampus}, function (err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
  })
});
```

I am using following schema:

```
var RuimteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
campusAfkorting: String,
verdieping: Number,
naam: String,
type: String,
omschrijving: String,
oppervlakte: Number,
x: Number,
y: Number,
breedte: Number,
hoogte: Number,
capaciteit: Number,
openingsuren: String,
beamer: {
    aanwezig: String,
    type: String,
    datumLamp: String
},
"acties": [
    {
        "id": Number,
        "datumAanmaak": String,
        "type": String,
        "omschrijving": String,
        "prioriteit": String,
        "datumUitvoering": String,
        "opgelost": String,
        "kostprijs": Number
    }
]
}, { collection: 'Ruimtes'})
```

I process the returned data in AngularJS and output it in a table using ng-repeat:
[image]
When I inspect the scope using batarang it shows that "beamer" and "acties" are empty ("beamer: [object Object]").

[image]

I need the data inside of them (aanwezig, type and datumLamp) to show on my application.

What am i doing wrong or how can I enable some kind of eager loading?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your debug console try to see values for acties[0] and beamer[0]

Comment: Output: $scope.ruimtes[0].beamer[0] ==> "[" and for "acties":
$scope.ruimtes[0].acties[0] ==> "[object Object]"

Comment: Are you sure the data is properly stored in your database?

Comment: I thinks it is, this is an example of a document in my mongoDB: http://oi41.tinypic.com/1q0mqw.jpg

Do I need to specifiy the type in my schema for "beamer:{..." and "acties":  [..." For example "acties": array [..." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you have to define a schema for embedded arrays and that the double name are not allowed:

```
var ActieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "id": Number,
  "datumAanmaak": String,
  "type": String,
  "omschrijving": String,
  "prioriteit": String,
  "datumUitvoering": String,
  "opgelost": String,
  "kostprijs": Number
 })

var RuimteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  campusAfkorting: String,
  verdieping: Number,
  naam: String,
  type: String,
  omschrijving: String,
  oppervlakte: Number,
  x: Number,
  y: Number,
  breedte: Number,
  hoogte: Number,
  openingsuren: String,
  beamer: { aanwezig: String, typeBeamer: String, datumLamp: String},
  "acties": [ActieSchema]
}, { collection: 'Ruimtes'})
```